# Possible to change/append file name of file uploaded in ltng cmp?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-community

I’m using flows to gather information in a stepped process, and have found that I’m not able to append or change the file names of files.

Is it possible to change the file name after it’s been uploaded from a ltng cmp or controller?

The issue is that people in the community will upload documents such as “scan1” “scan2” and it would be nice to make it “resume - scan1” etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is super MacGyver but here it goes.

Problem: Files uploaded in a flow on a community, can't have their names changed by the community user. This is annoying because files get uploaded as "scan1.pdf".

Solution: After creating the initial flow to be on the community, create another flow and process in Process Builder. Also create 2 new fields in your object to store the temporary name and ID number. THIS ONLY WORKS WITH SINGLE FILE UPLOAD.

1. Create a flow to go on community.

   1a. Create screen asking for file upload using forcecontent:FileUpload component. Assign ContentDocumentID output of FileUpload to collection variable.

   1b. Create whatever logic you want to make a custom file name (I used radio buttons for the user to specify what they were uploading, and used a Decision Element to update a tickbox on the object as well.)

   1c. Create Loop Element. Loop through CollectionVariable of ContentDocumentId. Assign current value to a text variable.

   1d. Update Object Custom field CustomFieldId to CurrentLoopedValue Variable. Update Object Custom field CustomFieldNewFileName to whatever you want (either static or from a radio button in my case).
2. Create new AutoLaunched Flow. (Called Update File Name)

   2a. Create Update Record Element for ContentDocument

   2b. Lookup Id to variable (create one - input type)

   2c. Update Title of ContentDocument to variable (create one - input type)

   2d. Save and activate all flows.
3. Create Process Builder Process.

   3a. Choose object your File is related to.

   3b. Criteria is whenever those fields are changed. (they can be AND'd since the update is in a single transaction from the first flow we made).

   3c. Choose Flow Action. Choose the flow you just made for Updating File Name.

   3d. Input variables should be the fields on your Object.

   ContentDocumentId = CustomFieldId

   Title = CustomFileName

Click save and active and test!